# 'requestReview()' was deprecated in iOS 14.0

Tags: swift, storekit, ios14

In iOS 14, Xcode is showing a warning:

> requestReview()' was deprecated in iOS 14.0

I'm using StoreKit to ask review automatically in my app.

```
func requestReview() {
    guard shouldRequestReview else {return}
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    lastRequest = Date()
}
```

[image]

How to get rid of that warning?

Comment: @ Dc7 - In your code it looks like you are logging the dates when you last showed the request review, would you mind sharing your logic? I have an app in the AppStore and some users report that they keep getting the RateApp request and I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong. After 10 launches, I ask the user to rate the app but I only call the `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` method, no other logic and I don't log any dates. Would you mind sharing your logic before calling the `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` method?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

### iOS 16+

There is now a new [RequestReviewAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requestreviewaction) that is available as an environment value:

```swift
private struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview

    var body: some View {
        Button("Review") {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                requestReview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### iOS 14+

#### Quick solution

```
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
    }
}
```

*Note: according to some comments it's more reliable with `DispatchQueue.main.async`*

#### Convenient solution

Here's a true *one-liner*:

```
SKStoreReviewController.requestReviewInCurrentScene()
```

but first you need to create the following extension in `SKStoreReviewController`:

```
extension SKStoreReviewController {
    public static func requestReviewInCurrentScene() {
        if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                requestReview(in: scene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/PhantomKit) with different Swift extensions including [`requestReviewInCurrentScene()`](https://github.com/pawello2222/PhantomKit/blob/main/Sources/Swift/Extensions/StoreKit%2BExt.swift).</sub>

---

#### Explanation

The `requestReview` function was deprecated in iOS 14:

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 10.3, deprecated: 14.0)
open class func requestReview()
```

You need to use the `requestReview(in:)` function instead:

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
open class func requestReview(in windowScene: UIWindowScene)
```

**Possible solutions**

- Custom extension

You can create the following extension:

```
extension UIApplication {
    var currentScene: UIWindowScene? {
        connectedScenes
            .first { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive } as? UIWindowScene
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.currentScene {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
}
```

- Universal *one-liner*:

```
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
}
```

- *single scene* solution (for iOS)

```
if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
}
```

Comment: This is NOT ideal solution on iPad IMO. When you have multiple WindowScenes opened, the review popup shows up in `first` connectedScene even the window is in background.

Comment: @toshi0383 Yes, you're right. When I was answering this I thought about iOS only. Please see the updated answer for multiple scenes.

Comment: @pawello2222 , do you know the answer of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272521/requestreview-doesnt-work-if-i-open-my-app-manually

Comment: What would the equivalent solution for macOS? The great thing about the old function was that it was OS-agnostic.

Comment: i would add   DispatchQueue.main.async { } to requestReviewInCurrentScene()'s body

Comment: Please note that ‘@Envitonment(\.requestReview)’ shouldn’t be used in a button as AppStore limits the number of requests to review the app. Once the user has submitted a review, new requests are blocked and button will appear unresponsive in production app

Answer (score 61):

**Simple solution for iOS(13 & above) and macOS**

**iOS (Swift 5+):**

```
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
        }
    } else if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    }
```

**macOS:**
Don't forget to replace your Apple ID with in URL "id123456789"

```
guard let writeReviewURL = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id123456789?action=write-review") else {
      print("Invalid URL")
      return
}
NSWorkspace.shared.open(writeReviewURL)
```

Comment: What would the equivalent solution for macOS? The great thing about the old function was that it was OS-agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

I made a small wrapper over SKStoreReviewController that saves the headache of supporting different versions of ios. Also it works for macOS.

```
// Review after 3 launches
AppReview.requestIf(launches: 3)

// Review after 5 days
AppReview.requestIf(days: 5)

// Review after 3 launches and 5 days
AppReview.requestIf(launches: 3, days: 5)
```

https://github.com/mezhevikin/AppReview

Answer (score 0):

iOS 16 has a new way to do it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/requestreviewaction

In my tests it is crucial to do it on the main queue. Otherwise the dialogue is unreliable.

```
private struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.requestReview) private var requestReview

    var body: some View {
        Button("Ask for Review") {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                requestReview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -8):

As `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview` is deprecated in ios14
You can use `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)` from ios14
Sample code is below

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
    }
} else if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
    SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
}
```

Comment: This is the same answer as the previous one (with the same bad formatting).

Comment: inexcitus please correct formatting