# requestReview doesn't work if I open my app manually

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storekit

I am using the following code to request review prompt, it works and I can see the review prompt shown when I am debugging my app from Xcode. However, when I tap the app icon to open my app on my iPad directly, I can't see the review prompt shown, what is wrong?

It is iPadOS 15.0, Xcode 13.0

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }) as? UIWindowScene {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview(in: scene)
        }
    } else if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
        SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
    }
}
```

Comment: The icon that you tap on your iPad directly, does it have a little yellow circle next to the app's name?

Comment: No, it doesn't have

Comment: When you are tapping on the icon, has the app on your iPad been installed through Xcode or downloaded from the App Store?